# Configure dual wired and wireless network connections on ubuntu and configure priority at application or ip level

Tags: networking, ssh, network-manager, internet

I have a desktop with wired connection. I'm planning to get a wifi receiver as well.
I need to configure dual internet on my system.
Further, I need my browsing traffic to go via wifi and my ssh connections to go via wired connection.
Just to explain the motivation: my wired connection is high speed but limited monthly capacity while wifi connection is slow speed but cheaper.

How can I achieve this? A lot of my browsing traffic is through youtube so if something based on ip can be configured then that would be great.

I'm operating on Ubuntu 16.04

Thanks,